# Why $g$ is continuous on A?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of Schwarz Lemma below:

> [image]

But I do not understand why $g$ is continuous on A? we do not know the formula for $f$ and so we do not know $f'(0),$ could someone explain this to me,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quotient of continuous functions is continuous as long as the denominator is nonzero. So $g$ is continuous on $A\setminus\{0\}$. At $0$, we have by definition of derivative that
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{f(z)}z=f'(0),
$$
since $f(0)=0$.